# Eclipse, Android Plug-in, Install New Software just says "pending"

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to install the Android plug-in for Eclipse (32 bit Windows 7 - the Eclipse-Java-Indigo release), following the instructions here.

[Mike Plate](http://www.mikeplate.com/2009/10/27/getting-ready-for-android-development/)

The trouble is eclipse just says "Pending", in the Install New Updates window, with nothing else seemingly going on, after I put in the URL:

[Google Android Eclipse](https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is often a problem with proxy settings. If you're behind a firewall (or using settings which were configured under one) go to Window -> Preferences -> General -> Network Connections and configure it properly.

Comment: Actually, I assume the URL given is wrong, because https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse/ gives a 404 if I go to it with my browser!

Comment: Oh, I read that it doesn't respond to general requests from browsers.  In any case, network admin confirms it's making a socks connection, but then doing nothing further.

Comment: Nope, that's the right URL. It doesn't work in the browser because Eclipse has its own protocol of where to look for software. Have you tried installing software from other Eclipse update sites? Try subclipse, for example.

Comment: Ok, further to previous comment, it's probably trying to connect via. socks 5 - but our network only has socks 4.  Admin is going to run the 5 version to see if it then works.

Comment: I tried to fix the Proxy but it still is not working. Isn't there a manual way we can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Close Firewall and virus program and try again. it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just disabled the Anti virus and it worked for me.

Comment: Anti Virus shouldn't block eclipse from installling new software unless you say explicitly not to install those types of files.