# android - eclipse helio's to indigo with android sdk

Tags: android, eclipse

Present i am using eclipse3.6(helios) with android sdk. Now i want to update helios to indigo. Suppose i am doing this then integration of android sdk is required or not. please help me how to do this

Answer (score 1):

No Android will be By Default in Eclipse if you Update.

Following are the Steps for Update

1. Window > Preferences > Install/Update > Available Software Sites
2. Click 'Add'
3. Enter URL: http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo
4. Click 'Ok'

Comment: Actually i am trying to update the  integrated android sdk with eclipse.that's why i am asking this?

Comment: But your question is regarding update eclipse, so i gave u such poings.

Comment: Try this answer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7410305/installing-the-adt-plugin-for-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Fist download and install one of the Eclipse Indigo packages (the **Eclipse IDE for Java Developers** is what I recommend). Make sure you do **not** install it into the same directory on top of your existing Eclipse; install it to a new location. You can use your existing workspace, however.

Then follow the instructions at http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html#installing to install the latest version of the Android Development Tools (ADT).